# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Top Navigation Bar drop down

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, navigation, top-link-bar

I have tried almost everything. I have been reading the blog from this [Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31208/sharepoint-2010-foundation-top-navigation-bar-drop-down-menu), but it does not explain how can I make drop down menus work on multiple top navigation links. Doing changes as the blog says won't do it. The blog owners pictures show multiple links having drop downs but I can't get them to work.

I did some changes to the masterpage and now I have navbar drop down structure that puts every Subsite (X,Y,Z) under the Home page.

I wanted it to be like **[THIS](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69005616/examptoforum2.png)**

Is my whole site collection structure a mess or what is the problem with this?

My masterpage code now:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
 ID="SiteMapProvider"
 Runat="server"
 EnableViewState="false"
 DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
 UseSimpleRendering="true"
 UseSeparateCss="false"
 Orientation="Horizontal"
 StaticDisplayLevels="1"
 MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="7"
 SkipLinkText=""
 CssClass="s4-tn"/>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="SiteMapDataSource1"/>
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
    <Template_Controls>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource
         ShowStartingNode="True"
         SiteMapProvider="SiteMapProvider"
         id="topSiteMap"
         runat="server"
         StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
    </Template_Controls>
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

Comment: Could you post your site structure and how it's being translated into the menu bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to change StaticDisplayLevels="1" to StaticDisplayLevels="2"

Code:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
 ID="SiteMapProvider"
 Runat="server"
 EnableViewState="false"
 DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
 UseSimpleRendering="true"
 UseSeparateCss="false"
 Orientation="Horizontal"
 StaticDisplayLevels="2"
 MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="7"
 SkipLinkText=""
 CssClass="s4-tn"/>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I managed to get the navbar working except the alphabetical order. The problem was that one and only number you referred to.

Comment: Good to hear that it works now. Please accept the answer by pressing the finch button, so this question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using publishing sites via Navigation make sure that View Pages/Sites is also checked, otherwise no site will be visible.