# SP Foundation 2010: Drop down menu in alphabetical order

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, navigation, dropdown, top-link-bar

I did get the drop down menu work with the instructions given to me in [HERE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/34420/7949) and now I have new problem with it: navigation bar is in alphabetical order which I would like to change to predefined.

So, how can I get the auto-arrange alphabetical function off or change it to order desired?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the navigation items in manual order mode. Go to Site Settings > (look and Feel) **Navigation** (../_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx) Within the page you can choose for **Sort manually**. Then you can use **Navigation Editing and Sorting** to give it your sorting.

Comment: That's probably the easiest way but I have the Foundation version which isn't supporting that function, in other words I don't have that Navigation-"button" and the url gives an error.

Comment: Ah oke. But then you'll probably see the option Top link bar in the 'Look and Feel' section. Within that page you can choose 'change order'.

Comment: I have made the correct order from there at the beginning but this code with drop downs seems to override it. I'm so lost with this..

Comment: I guess you have to dive into the tutorial, and figure out step by step what the effects are.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no out-of-the-box way of achieving this. You will need to define your own SP list and perhaps use the SharePoint:aspMenu control or something similar to point to that list and their columns. That way you could specify a field to sort by etc.

The way the out-of-the-box solution works that you tried is that it goes by structure on your site. It has nothing to do with the order you normally specify using the top link bar/navigation settings. Same thing goes for what sites you may or may not want to include in your navigation.